# JPanel custom paint

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint

I am having an issue painting a JPanel. It paints correctly, however when I resize the parent container, the JPanel gets painted at the top left corner of the window, as well as in the correct position.

The JPanel has a custom paint method, that paints a set of components that don't belong to any JPanel (including it). These are added to the JPanel immediately before their paint method is called, and is removed immediately after:

```
  paintOnto.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
  paintOnto.add(getPaintableComponent());
  getPaintableComponent().paint(g);
  paintOnto.remove(getPaintableComponent());
  paintOnto.setIgnoreRepaint(false);
```

paintOnto is a reference to the JPanel, getPaintableComponent() returns a JComponent that is to be drawn. g is the Graphics object passed through from the JPanel paint method.

The add/remove code was not required in mac at all, but under windows without it the components didnt paint at all.

This issue is only present in windows and ubuntu, not mac. Other systems are untested.

Any ideas what could be causing it? I have checked the position of the JPanel whenever it is painted, and it never is positioned at the top left corner.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

TRy to save `AffineTransform` of the `graphics` before and restore it after painting.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with AffineTransform, and can't find any reference to it belonging to a Graphics object, could you provide a code snippet?

Comment: Cast the graphics to Graphics2D and use public AffineTransform getTransform() method.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that, but its not resolved the issue. I have discovered that every component I dynamically add to the view is being painted twice, once in the correct location, and once in the same position, but relative to a component about 3 layers up.

Is there a way of painting a component onto the screen without adding it to a container? I get a window exception whenever I try.

Comment: Try disabling double buffering

Comment: @GuillaumePolet you are a genius!! I've been working on that for two days now! I would love to know what caused it, but at least now its fixed :) Thanks very much